# How do I sum columns in a CSV file when rows match with Python without Pandas

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that has Names in Column A and amount spent in column D.  I am trying to figure out how to get a sum of amount spent based on Column A. Fill disclosure.  This is part of an assignment.  We cant use Pandas or other prebuilt data tools.

It looks similar to this

```
Name, DatePurchased, DayOfWeek, AmountSpent
John, 01/01/21, Mon, 5000
John, 01/03/21. Wed, 50
Bill, 01/01/21, Mon, 10000
Suzy, 01/01/21, Mon, 15000
John, 01/08/21, Mon, 5000
Suzy, 01/08/21, Mon, 5000
```

As far I have gotten so far is import csv and opening the file.

```
import csv
with open('sales.csv') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
```

I THINK, I need use some sort of loop to make a dictionary with Name being the key and the corresponding values in Column D as the keys, but I am stuck.

Since it is an assignment, I dont expect the full answer, but some direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Python has a 'Set' data type which is an unordered, unique list. Just build a set consisting of key-value pairs from column A (e.g., [ {"John": 0}, {"Bill": 0}, ... ]) and then go through each value in the Set and add up all of the matching amounts spent. You'll need to initialize the list with identical spend values before summing the totals in this case. There are many other way to do this as well if you don't like this approach, and I would also recommend that you look into the datatypes available in Python, as well as the filter() and reduce() functions.

Comment: Look up bag of words methods in python and that should give you a method of a creating a dictionary with a string key and an int or numeric value.